# Find Max() Value from DataTable - Varchar() Column?

Tags: c#

I have a DataTable MyDtb1. And i have column "sl_no" varchar(10);
With this sl_no coloumn I have the value like the below manner.

```
MyDtb1.sl_no Column Values

Search - Zero'th Row
1 - 1 st Row
2 -2 nd Row
3 - 3 rd Row
4 - 4 th Row
Null - 5 th row
```

From the above I want to select the MAX(value) of sl_no and the result has to be "4"

Thanks for the Ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    int x;
    var maxVal = MyDtb1.AsEnumerable()
      .Max (r => int.TryParse(r.Field<string>("sl_no"), out x) ? (int?)x : null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
List<string> testList = new List<string> {
    "Search",
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    null                
    };
int num;
int maxNumeric = testList.Where(x => int32.TryParse(x, out num)).Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).Max();
```

Comment: Is there some reason you're parsing to `double` and then converting to `int`? Int32 has its own `TryParse` method...

Comment: @djacobson, no good reason =) Typed it out too quick to think about it - corrected, thanks